# Talend Startup error, Talend twebservice component error

Tags: web-services, jboss, talend-mdm

I have encountered a problem with one of my twebservice components, which seems to originate from the apache cxf jar. I see the error during startup also.

```
WARN  [org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerImpl] Loading Bus extensions via META-INF/cxf/bus-extensions.xml (found url jar:file:/data5/TalendEE/jboss-4.2.2.GA/server/default/tmp/deploy/tmp3204124133425837210tem.ear-contents/lib/z.cxf-2.2.5.jar!/META-INF/cxf/bus-extensions.xml) is deprecated.  Use META-INF/cxf/bus-extensions.txt instead.


Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unexpected error during load of: org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistry, msg=Implementing class
    at org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader.loadClassImpl(RepositoryClassLoader.java:560)
    at org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader.loadClass(RepositoryClassLoader.java:415)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 164 more
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
```

Comment: Are you bundling a apache cxf jar with your application - it looks like your getting ClassNotFoundException caused by IncompatibleClassChangeError  which version of JBoss, which version of CXF is JBoss using and what version of CXF is on your IDE build path?

Comment: The cxf jar is bundled with the webapp which is done by talend studio IDE itself. How do i check what version of cxf jboss is using?

Comment: What version of JBoss are you using, e.g. Wildfly or EAP and is it 4, 5, 6 or 7, based on that we/you can figure out the CXF version

Comment: This is a jboss 4.2.2GA server that comes bundled with the Talend MDM application.

Comment: According to this blurb "migrating from from JBoss 4.2.2 to Wildfly 8. The old project was using Spring 2.5.5, Hibernate 3.6.7 and CXF 2.2.7" - it's CXF 2.2.7, what version of CXF do you have bundled with the webapp?

Comment: It should be 2.2.5 version, according to the error trace (first line). But this is bundled with the application itself, should I change it manually?.